Symbol $X_{n}=O\left(a_{n}\right)$ a.s.

(Borel-Cantelli lemma). Let $X_{n}$ be a sequence of random variables, and let $a_{n}$ be a sequence of nonnegative numbers. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\left|X_{n}\right|>a_{n}\right)$ is finite, then
$X_{n} \leq a_{n}$ almost surely, or $X_{n}=O\left(a_{n}\right)$ almost surely.

What's the formal definition of $X_{n}=O\left(a_{n}\right)$ almost surely?
Let $A_{n}=\left\{|X_n|\le a_n\right\}$,
from above we know that $\mathbb{P}(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\omega\in A_n\text{ for all }n\ge n_0(\omega)\right\})=1.$
So I guess "$X_{n}=O\left(a_{n}\right)$ a.s." means there is  a constant $C>0$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|X_n|}{ a_n}\le C )=1$.However, I'm not sure if my understanding is correct.

I would expect that's what it means.

The constant could depend on $\omega$. $\displaystyle\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}|X_{n}(\omega)|/a_{n}<\infty$ for every $\omega$ except maybe for a set of $0$ probability.

@Mr.GandalfSauron Your definition includes more cases than mine.Actually, it means the sequence of radom variables $\left{\frac{X_n}{a_n}\right}{n\in\mathbb{N}}$  finite almost surely,rather than $\left{\frac{X_n}{a_n}\right}{n\in\mathbb{N}}$almost surely boundedness.I'm not clear about $X_n=O(a_n)\text { a.s.}$ formal definition,different interpretations can cause trouble.

almost surely just means that you need to apply the usual definition of $O(a_{n})$ to each sequence $X_{n}(\omega)/a_{n}$, omega by omega. So if you fix an $\omega$, it just means that $X_{n}(\omega)$ viewed as a real sequence should satisfy $O(a_{n})$. Now the constant $C$ can depend on $\omega$. i.e. you need not have a uniform $C$ such that $X_{n}(\omega)/a_{n}\leq C$ for all large enough $n\geq N(\omega)$.
